# Ember Testing route redirect

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js, ember-testing

I am very new to Ember and have never written a test case before. I currently have a route that is being used as a base class and will be extended by other routes to use the same behavior for redirecting. Here is what the route looks like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function(){
    var user = this.modelFor('application').user;
      if(Ember.isEmpty(user.get('auth'))){
        this.transitionTo('login');
      }
  },
  model: function(){
   return this.modelFor('application').user;
  }
});
```

So testing this manually works great, if I type in the direct url for a screen it will redirect to the login. This is the functioning code we want. I was tasked with writing unit test and have not been able to turn up anything that I found useful. This is probably my inexperience with understanding things but I need to figure out how to test this code. I would love some help and some explanation as well as to what is being done. I have to do unit tests and lots of other things for this ember project and being very new I've already wasted 2 days researching how to test this one class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, for this route there is nothing to test with unit test. You need to write acceptance test for this route.

Look at the [Ember Guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/testing/testing-routes/) for testing routes. You don't have any property or action to write a unit test for this route. Write [acceptance tests](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/testing/acceptance/).

Comment: Thank you I will look into this. You are correct in that it is indeed an acceptance test so I will mark this answer correct. However I still need to figure out the testing, would it be okay if I have troubles and continue to post here?